# How to get count for specfic month and group by year with $match in MongoDB

Tags: sql, mongodb, shell, mongo-shell

i want a equivalent query to

```
    SELECT YEAR(displayDate) AS YEAR, 
           count(_id) as Total
    from collection
    where Month(displayDate)=1 
    group by  YEAR(displayDate);
```

If you clearly go into the SQL query i want total `_id` counts for `month=1` and group by `year`

The output would get for this is

```
-----------------------
Year   |  Total
-----------------------
2016   | 30
2017   | 45
2018   | 60
-----------------------
```

Tried equivalent query to get in Mongo

```
db.collection.aggregate(
{$match: {}},
{$group : {
_id : {$year : "$displayDate"},
count : {$sum : 1}
}})
```

But using the above mongo query am getting total for all 12 months, i just want for month 1, how to filter this in `$match` for month 1. Where `displayDate` is the field for date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use [$month](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/month/)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            $expr: {
                $eq: [{$month: "$displayDate"}, 1]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: {$year: "$displayDate"},
            count: {$sum: 1}
        }
    }
])
```